# redirect() Adds a question mark before the URI segment

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've recently enabled `enable_query_strings` in CodeIgniter's config because when i tried to redirect to something like `redirect('/blog?foo=bar')` it removes the GET parameters but `enable_query_strings` fixed that..

The issue is that now when i do:

```
redirect('/blog');
```

it adds a `?` to the url: `http://www.domain.com/?/blog`

How to fix that? or how to solve the primary issue without enabling `query_strings`?

Comment: Either en- or disable it. But don't mix. `redirect('c=blog')`, see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend just using `header('location:/blog?foo=bar');` instead.

Answer (score 2):

[Read up](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) on what `enable_query_strings` actually does and make sure this is actually what you want. It is *not* in fact a way to simply enable `$_GET`.

Confusing, I know. Please check out the [latest version](http://codeigniter.com/downloads/) (2.0.2 currently) and enable the config option `allow_get_array` instead. This allows normal `$_GET` support to CI.

`enable_query_strings` was some weird psuedo-experimental feature that persists in new versions for some reason (do people really use it?). It is not, and never was, a way to use `$_GET` in the normal usage that we all know.

EDIT: Looks like *all* the url helpers, and all the functions that figure out your urls for you are busted if you enable this.

From the User Guide on `enable_query_strings`:

> Please note: If you are using query strings you will have to build
>   your own URLs, rather than utilizing the URL helpers (and other
>   helpers that generate URLs, like some of the form helpers) as these
>   are designed to work with segment based URLs.

So, if you're *sure* this is what you want, [Karl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680874/redirect-adds-a-question-mark-before-the-uri-segment/6681017#6681017) (using vanilla php's `header` to redirect) is pretty much your only hope. Or, you can try to provide a full URL, seeing as `base_url()` is probably broken now too (?):

```
redirect('http://full-urls-are-tedious.com/blog');
```

But this may not even work...

Answer (score 2):

hope this will help you ! no need to change htaccess,just change your code.

```
redirect(base_url()."controller_name/function_name");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using query strings? CodeIgniters router will take care of this for you. You can create a router path that is shorter is you want but the basic structure is this:

```
http://www.somedomain.com/controller/function/param1/param2/...etc
```

So you could just go to this:

```
http://www.somedomain.com/blog/foo/bar
```

or

```
http://www.somedomain.com/blog/post/3
```

You can also use the router config to change it to something like this:

```
http://www.somedomain.com/blog/3
```

You really should use your CRUD functions that come with it.
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: I know that, sometimes you have to not use pretty urls.